# Adding References of Crystal Report DLLs

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2012, crystal-reports

My OS is Windows 7 x64. Running VS Professional 2012. I'm working in a software written in C# and developed for .NET Framework 4.0 that uses Crystal Report. I've installed Crystal Report for developers version 13.0.5 on the machine.

I want to copy the required DLLs of Crystal Report to the output folder of the project. The purpose is to pack them with the installer so that the PC where the software will be installed won't be required to install Crystal Report.

I created a folder called DLLs and put the required Crystal Report DLLs in that folder. Then in the C# project's References node in solution explorer, I've added the DLLs located in DLLs folder. When I look in the added DLL's Property > Path, surprisingly I find that the path holds the path of the DLL from where I copied (C:\Program Files... instead of D:\Work...).

Why is this happening? How can I add reference to the copied DLL, not the original DLL?

Comment: [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3548731/visual-studio-2010-add-reference-is-copying-dll-to-bin-directory) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3635716/visual-studio-copy-dll-refrences-to-output-folder), perhaps.

Comment: Can you try to copy dll into D folder and then try to reference it in your project again and then check again. I am just guessing

Comment: I have deployed Crystal Reports(a previous version) with my application, and I have never been able to install it without using their(Crystal Report's) install. I am not sure how successful copying the dll's will be.

Comment: @Brian: my problem is slightly different.

Comment: @AshReva: tried it. the effect is same.

Comment: Yes, it is possible to install CR without it's installer. You can create an installer using Intsall Shield, i know that because i've done it. Now, just don't ask me HOW cause i did that over 3 years ago. I still have that Installer on my PC at work and we have been using it since then on all our clients. You could make some research about creating an CR installer using install shield.

Comment: btw, that installer only installs the required DLLs, not the whole Crystal Reports Application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short Answer: Crystal Reports wont work without installing on client machines.
What you can do is doing some research about what does the Crystal Reports Installer does and doit yourself whithin you application. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1695546/deploy-crystal-report-dlls-only-using-clickonce-without-using-prerequisite-msi)

Other  sources: [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa287928%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15130508/cannot-load-file-or-assembly-crystal-decisions-windows-forms-version-13-0-2000/15163363#15163363), or google it.

Regards